# Storing MultipartFile in HttpSession

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to create a Spring Boot application which uploads files and stores them in an HttpSession for future usage (just for educational purpose). I have a problem with files' **MultipartFile getSize()**. It returns non zero values in POST handler method, and return zeroes every time I get them from HttpSession in GET handler method. At the same time **getOriginalFileName()** return correct names. So my "Loaded Files:" table displays file names correctly, but sizes are zeroes.

Maybe I'm conceptually wrong trying to store MultipartFile in HttpSession?

As templates I'm using Thymeleaf.

Here is a template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      lang="en">
<head>
    <title>File Uploader</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files" id="files" multiple="multiple"/> <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload" id="upload"/>
    <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}"/>
</form>
<h3>Loaded files:</h3>
<table border="1px">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>File name</td>
        <td>Size</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr th:each="file : ${uploadedFiles}">
        <td th:text="${file.originalFilename}"/>
        <td th:text="${file.size}"/>
    </tr>
</table>
<form method="POST" action="confirm">
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm" name="confirm" id="confirm"/>
    <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a controller:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model, HttpSession httpSession) {
        List<MultipartFile> uploadedFiles = (List<MultipartFile>) httpSession.getAttribute("uploadedFiles");
        model.addAttribute("uploadedFiles", uploadedFiles);
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String index(@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files, HttpSession httpSession) {
        List<MultipartFile> uploadedFiles = (List<MultipartFile>) httpSession.getAttribute("uploadedFiles");
        if (uploadedFiles != null) {
            uploadedFiles.addAll(Arrays.asList(files));
        } else {
            uploadedFiles = Arrays.asList(files);
        }
        httpSession.setAttribute("uploadedFiles", uploadedFiles);
        return "redirect:";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some investigation I found that **MultipartFile** exists in the temporary directory only when Tomcat is processing request. Right after response it removes file. That's why size is zero. It is possible to store this data in memory or in the DB or somewhere else using custom structure.

Here is an example:

```
public class UploadedFile {
    private final String originalFilename;
    private final byte[] data;

    public UploadedFile(String fileName, byte[] data) {
        this.originalFilename = fileName;
        this.data = data.clone();
    }

    public String getOriginalFilename() {
        return originalFilename;
    }

    public byte[] getData() {
        return data.clone();
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return data.length;
    }
}
```

In case of in memory storage MultipartFile class could be used. If the file not stored on the HDD it exists in memory as long as you have a reference on it.

Here is an example of the **application.properties** file:

```
multipart.file-size-threshold=10Mb
multipart.max-file-size=10Mb
multipart.max-request-size=10Mb
```

**multipart.file-size-threshold** forces all uploaded files up to 10MB to be stored in memory rather than HDD. By default it equals to 0 and all the files are stored on the HDD.

Also I found that using HttpSession is not an elegant decision.
**@SessionAttributes** annotation together with **Model** make this solution rather clear.

Here is the updated controller:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes(value = {"uploadedFiles"})
public class IndexController {
    @ModelAttribute("uploadedFiles")
    public List<UploadedFile> initUploadedFiles() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String index(Model model, @RequestParam MultipartFile[] files, @ModelAttribute("uploadedFiles") List<UploadedFile> uploadedFiles) {
        for (MultipartFile file : files) {
            try {
                uploadedFiles.add(new UploadedFile(file.getOriginalFilename(), file.getBytes()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Can't read file " + file.getOriginalFilename(), e);
            }
        }
        model.addAttribute("uploadedFiles", uploadedFiles);
        return "redirect:";
    }
}
```